# PHP no-one can register same name

Tags: php

I've searched web and I've found this code. I tried to rework it, so whenever someone registers with an name, someone else can't register with that same name. I've literally tried everything. Nothing've worked. So please, can someone help me with this code, so no-one else can register same name?

Register.php

```
    $check_email = $DBcon->query("SELECT email FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email'");
    $count=$check_email->num_rows;

    if ($count==0) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_users(username,email,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$hashed_password')";

        if ($DBcon->query($query)) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; úspešne zaregistrován !
                    </div>";
        }else {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; error pri registraci !
                    </div>";
        }

    } else {


        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; email již existuje !
                </div>";    


    $DBcon->close();
}
}
?>
```

DB: 
[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: `username` is unique?

Comment: As chris85 suggests, this should be enforced in your _database_ via a `UNIQUE` constraint, not at the PHP level.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your query to check both the username and email:

```
$check_email = $DBcon->query("SELECT email FROM tbl_users WHERE email='$email' OR username = '$uname'");
```

You should also have a unique index on the `username` column in the database. Then the `INSERT` query will get an error if you try to create a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped !

Comment: This works, but name and email doesn't save into DB... What am I doing wrong ? Code looks like this now : https://www.hastebin.com/oreseyoxig.xml

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Is it getting an error when it tries to insert? If so, what does `echo $DBcon->error` show?

Comment: Okay I figured out myself, it was some kind of "parse" problem, missing {/} I copied the base file and now everything works fine.